# How to auto generate files in development mode in nuxtjs?

Tags: npm, nuxt.js

I am creating a SPA application, but after every change I enter the command "npm run generate" to generate static files.
How can I run the "npm run dev" command so that it automaticly creates files in the "dist" folder?

My backend server (nestjs) connects to the "dist" folder and grabs the index.html file from there.

Comment: So, you do want to trigger a build upon an update each time you touch a line of code in your project? This will be pretty hardcore in terms of wait because you'll need to wait several minutes for it to complete. Can't you just connect in some other way? Also, did you checked the content of `.nuxt`, there is maybe something for you there.